# Floodfill function in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, colors, image-segmentation, flood-fill

What is the meaning of floating range and fixed range given in the [documentation of floodfill function](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#ga366aae45a6c1289b341d140839f18717)??

I used the floodfill function to a grayscale image shown below. The image has three regions of varying intensities.

[image: input image]

1. outer rectangle = 170
2. inner ellipse = 175
3. inner rectangle = 180

I want to floodfill the regions of 170 and 175 together as single connected component and region with 180 as separate one.

I modified the  [code from here](http://nghiaho.com/?p=1102) and function as follows:

```
  #include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

void FindBlobs(const cv::Mat &binary, std::vector < std::vector<cv::Point2i> > &blobs);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread("blob.png", 0); // force greyscale

    if(!img.data) {
        std::cout << "File not found" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    cv::namedWindow("binary");
    cv::namedWindow("labelled");

    cv::Mat output = cv::Mat::zeros(img.size(), CV_8UC3);

    cv::Mat binary=img.clone();
    std::vector < std::vector<cv::Point2i > > blobs;
        
    FindBlobs(binary, blobs);

    // Randomy color the blobs
    for(size_t i=0; i < blobs.size(); i++) {
        unsigned char r = 255 * (rand()/(1.0 + RAND_MAX));
        unsigned char g = 255 * (rand()/(1.0 + RAND_MAX));
        unsigned char b = 255 * (rand()/(1.0 + RAND_MAX));

        for(size_t j=0; j < blobs[i].size(); j++) {
            int x = blobs[i][j].x;
            int y = blobs[i][j].y;

            output.at<cv::Vec3b>(y,x)[0] = b;
            output.at<cv::Vec3b>(y,x)[1] = g;
            output.at<cv::Vec3b>(y,x)[2] = r;
        }
    }

    cv::imshow("binary", img);
    cv::imshow("labelled", output);
    cv::waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}

void FindBlobs(const cv::Mat &binary, std::vector < std::vector<cv::Point2i> > &blobs)
{
    blobs.clear();

    cv::Mat label_image;
    binary.convertTo(label_image, CV_32FC1); 

    int label_count = 2; 

    for(int y=0; y < binary.rows; y++) {
    {
     for(int x=0; x < binary.cols; x++) {
         {   if((int)label_image.at<float>(y,x) < 150) {  //start labelling only when pixel > 150
             {
         continue;
             }

            cv::Rect rect;
            cv::floodFill(label_image, cv::Point(x,y), cv::Scalar(label_count), &rect, cv::Scalar(0), cv::Scalar(6), 4+CV_FLOODFILL_FIXED_RANGE);

            std::vector <cv::Point2i> blob;

            for(int i=rect.y; i < (rect.y+rect.height); i++) {
            {   for(int j=rect.x; j < (rect.x+rect.width); j++) {
                {   if((int)label_image.at<float>(i,j) != label_count) {
                    {    continue;
                    }

                    blob.push_back(cv::Point2i(j,i));
                }
            }

            blobs.push_back(blob);

            label_count++;
        }
    }
}
```

I used fixed range using the flag CV_FLOODFILL_FIXED_RANGE(**is it correct the way I used??**)

I specify the **loDiff=0 and upDiff=6**.

I **expected**  that when seed becomes 170, all points in range 170-0 to 170+6 ie **170 to 176** (**outer rectangle & inner ellipse**) are floodfilled with same label and since inner rectangle is 180, it would have different label.

However I get the output as below:-

[image]

**the outer rectangle and inner ellipse are not having the same label**. What might be the mistake?

expected o/p : inner ellipse also be of orange color(same as outer rectangle)

Comment: Did you try to only applying a flood fill, i.e. discard this `FindBlobs` and etc, ? Applying `floodFill` on the point `(0, 0)` and replacing the flooded region to grayscale intensity using the same parameters as yours, this is the resulting image: http://i.imgur.com/yN5Qn96.png (disconsidering the artifacts introduced in the image shown in the question, this is the result you are after).

Comment: I dont want this to work only for this image... i need that areas in a particular range with a tolerance of say, 0 to +5 ,ie 170-175(if 170 becomes seed value) be labeled as single component... I have to use FindBlobs since i check the condition **label_image.at<float>(y,x) < 150** which means I start labeling only when pixel is greater than 150...If I start at (0,0) it will work in this case because I know that (0,0) is 170 which is greater than 150.

Comment: Misunderstandings all the way. If all your code is working correctly, then it will also flood fill at (0, 0). This means you should be getting an output similar to that linked image. Since it does not give the same output, the problem is unrelated to flood fill. Thus the question is pointless.

Comment: The aim is to **label all the regions** which is done by the code as it iterates to check for unlabeled regions...I am asking that why doesnt my code provide output as your link... though I have passed the **parameters to floodFill function correctly**... it should have labelled outer rectangle and ellipse as in your link and inner rectangle as in mine...

Comment: but I dont understand why it is labeling the outer rectangle and ellipse differently? and **did you use CV_FLOODFILL_FIXED_RANGE** because the motive of this qn is to know what floating and fixed range means... if i use floating range I get the expected o/p... not with CV_FLOODFILL_FIXED_RANGE(**which i have used in my code**)

Comment: It doesn't seem the question is all about that flag, I could illustrate what the docs already say about it though. I did use it.

Comment: ok here is my understanding about the flag... **FIXED_RANGE** the filling starts at a location specified by user and uses pixel value at that location to compare for pixels in the given range[loDIFF & upDIFF](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/miscellaneous_image_transformations.html#cv-floodfill). I assume that **this happens for the entire image** (ie all pixels in the image which are in the given range will be labeled same).

Comment: in **FLOATING_RANGE** only **pixels in a 3*3 neighborhood are checked** to see whether they lie in the given range... here i **assume** that two pixels with same value but separated by other pixels for more than a 3*3 neighborhood will **not** be labeled same... please correct me if my wrong... thank you.